# messed up with loops cant find the logical mistake

Tags: c, nested-loops

Actually right now i am learning c and doing an excercise of looping and got messed up in a question.

my code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int i,j,k,spc,k;
   printf("\enter the number of rows:");
   scanf("%d",&rows);
   spc=rows+4-1;
   for(i=1;i<=rows;i++)
    { 
      for(k=spc;k>1;k--)
        { printf(" ");
         }
    for(j=1;j<=i:j++)
       printf("*");
    printf("\n")
    spc--;
    }
  }
```

https://www.w3resource.com/c-programming-exercises/for-loop/c-for-loop-exercises-14.php
and this is the reference for the answer by them whose excercise i am doing right now.
can you see any difference bw these codes.
please help me. 
thank you

Comment: You have `printf("*");` and they have `printf("* ");`.

Comment: What's wrong?  Are you getting output you weren't expecting?

Comment: This would be a good time to note that tools exist to compare files. You may want to explore some.

Comment: yes I am not getting the expexted output... actually  i am missing some spaces which should be printed there.

Comment: as ggloren suggested me something and it worked.. i got the desiered output

Comment: `k>=1` vs `k>1` is also different. It's a good practice to read your code line by line and compare yourself in the future--probably more educational than us doing it for you. Kudos for not just copying and pasting their code, though.

Comment: There are several syntax errors in this code.  Please *paste* the code you're actually running, don't just try to type it in.  You'll make mistakes, as you've just seen.

Comment: yes bro in future i will take care of that and thanks for helping me through this. actually i was stuck there from 2 days and i was totally cluesless what was going on..but now its done

Comment: bro thats the actual code i am running

Comment: Delineate intended executable sections  of each for loop explicitly using "{...}'.  This will aide readability and leave no question of your intent

Comment: actually i used curly braces in last ones but according to the flow of the program the last two lines should be excecuted under the first for loop for the proper results.i debugged the code and found that so I removed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i can see, you have small errors which you need to fix ,
first is, `int i,j,k,spc,k;`, here, 'k' is written twice, next is `scanf("%d",&rows);` but, `rows` is not declared anywhere, in this line,`for(j=1;j<=i:j++)`, you missed a semicolon and added colon instead, so replace it with `for(j=1;j<=i;j++)` and the last one is, `printf("\n")` ,in this line, you missed a semicolon! and for the desired output, you just need to add a space in `printf("*");` ,i.e, `printf("* ");`.Thats it.